# Difference between yieldTemplates and render to in IronRouter

Tags: meteor, iron-router

What is the difference betwwen these both routes for using yields in a template? For me both are doing the same:

```
Router.route('/', {
    name: 'home',
    action: function() {
        this.render('content', { to: 'content' });
        this.render('navigation', { to: 'navigation' });
    }
});

Router.route('/', {
    name: 'home',
    yieldTemplates: {
        'navigation':   { to: 'navigation' },
        'content':      { to: 'content' } 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are doing the same, it's a matter of preference which style you prefer.

However yieldTemplates has been deprecated.  It still works, but you should replace yieldTemplates with yieldRegions if you want to use this style.

[code here](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/9c369499c98af9fd12ef9e68338dee3b1b1276aa/lib/route_controller_client.js)

```
/**
 * The regionTemplates for the RouteController.
 */
RouteController.prototype.lookupRegionTemplates = function () {
  return this.lookupOption('yieldRegions') ||
    // XXX: deprecated
    this.lookupOption('regionTemplates') ||
    this.lookupOption('yieldTemplates') || {};
};
```

You can see yieldRegions documented in the [iron router guide.](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/)